# Excel VBA to go into cell in each sheet and refresh (F2+Enter)

Tags: excel, vba

I already have a macro that goes into cell F4 of each Sheet and renames that sheet that name (I am running a lot of indirects because I am pulling from a lot of different sheets). Every F4 cell on every sheet is linked to a Master sheet that has all the names - so when I change the Hardcode in the Master it changes cell F4 for that specific sheet. However, in order for the macro to run and that sheet to rename itself to whatever F4 is, I need to manually go to that sheet and click F2 and then Enter in cell F4 and then the Macro renames the sheet and everything else works. How can I have it so that it would do that automatically?

-Terribly sorry if this has been solved, read through a bunch of comments but none really addressed what I need

'''This is what I have for renaming sheets, just need to adjust it so that it "F2 and Enter"s itself after I change the master file, which in turn changes the value of cell F4"

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address(0, 0) = "F4" Then
    Sh.Name = Sh.Range("F4").Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't your macro just look at the Master sheet and find the new sheet names there?

Comment: +1 on @PeterT comment. Just make a `Worksheet_Change` event on the master sheet where it will trigger the sheet name change and that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this in as the `Worksheet_Change` event of your Master sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name <> Target.Parent.Name And sh.Name <> sh.Range("F4") Then
            sh.Name = sh.Range("F4")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will run each time a change is made to the Master sheet and if it sees a sheet (other than Master) that has a name differing to that sheets F4 value, it will correct it.

Keep in mind though, you need to ensure that no two sheets have an identical value in F4 as no two tabs can have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KickStart()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        sh.Select
        Range("F4").Select
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Gary's Student, that seems to be on the right track and I am only getting a Run-time error with method select of object _worksheet failed marking the sh.Select - im totally out of my league here so apologies if Im saying something ridiculous